# How to exclude package from build history in Yocto?

Tags: package, yocto, yocto-recipe

I have updated `BUILDHISTORY_FEATURES=image sdk` to avoid including the package directory in the build history. However, I am still seeing the package directory with numerous subdirectories in the build history. The package directory is smaller (5 MB) compared to when `BUILDHISTORY_FEATURES=image package sdk` (18 MB) and has fewer directories.

How can I completely exclude the package directory from the build history?